# If the Catholic Church teaches "babies and bonding", is having sex at an old age a sin?

Tags: catholicism, ethics, contraception

I was recently listening to a [podcast](https://www.catholic.com/audio/cot/the-case-against-ivf-with-stephanie-gray-connors) between [Stephanie Gray Connors](https://loveunleasheslife.com/about) and [Trent Horn](https://www.trenthorn.com) on the unethical nature of IVF. One argument that was brought up was the idea that the Catholic Church teaches "babies and bonding", which is why IVF and birth control are wrong. IVF doesn't have bonding, and birth control doesn't have babies.

But at a certain point, a woman becomes unable to have children. So after that point, would it be unethical for the man and woman to have sex (according to the Catholic Church)?

Comment: +1 Important question. "IVF and birth control are wrong" Only if you define 'birth control' narrowly. Natural family planning is OK according to the Catholic Church, at least some of the time.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather NFP is not typically thought of as birth "control." BC almost always refers to steps taken to have sex while also preventing pregnancy, whereas NFP is an abstention from sex in order to avoid pregnancies. Also often overlooked is the fact that NFP can also be a boon to couples trying to conceive, since it can tell them when to have sex in order to give them the greatest chance of pregnancy.

Comment: @jaredad7 Yes, a lot of the resources re NFP are aimed at helping to get people pregnant. But standard defn re BC is "regulation of the number of children born through the deliberate control or prevention of conception" If a couple is using NFP to prevent conception over, say, a monthly period (while still having sex over that period), seems to me that's BC. It is *strategic* engagement in sex in order to avoid pregnancies.

Comment: Don't know whether NFP is typically thought of as birth control, but here's the Mayo Clinic considering it so. "Natural family planning is a method of birth control that helps you predict when ovulation will happen" https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/birth-control/basics/natural-family-planning/hlv-20049454

Comment: Here's Kaiser Permanente including it under the category of 'birth control'. https://healthy.kaiserpermanente.org/health-wellness/birth-control/types/natural-family-planning

Comment: Here's WebMD "Natural family planning is a form of birth control that doesn't involve pills or devices." https://www.webmd.com/sex/birth-control/natural-family-planning-methods

Comment: @jaredad7 So I don't know whether NFP is typically thought of as BC or not. Certainly in some prominent medical web-sites it is.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather it’s considered a natural form of birth control, at least that’s the least complicated way to think of it. It definitely isn’t conventional in that it focuses on abstinence rather than just contraception pregnancy whenever you want to have sex.

Comment: @jaredad7 NFP is the _only_ form of Birth Control, the rest can only be thought of as 'Birth Prevention'.  `Normal people can only act so as to produce birth; and these people can only act so as to prevent birth.  - G.K.C. Babies and Distributism`

Comment: @OneGodtheFather yes that's exactly right. NFP is not a method of *preventing* pregnancy. Pregnancy doesn't need to be prevented if it can't happen in the first place because you are abstaining from sex. The Mayo Clinic is great at medicine, but when it comes to moral definitions, I wouldn't really trust a secular, worldly institute such as tehm.

Comment: @PeterTurner Birth Control is typically thought of as methods intended to *prevent* pregnancy/birth. But yes, if you wanted to call that birth prevention and call birth control something else, your distinction would be fitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not necessarily a sin.

Babies and Bonding is a euphamism for the procreative and unitive nature of the conjugal act.

St. Pope John Paul II devotes a large portion of his famous work "Love and Responsibility" to understanding the word "To Use" and it all comes down to whether or not one or both of the spouses is *using*  one another. If you can conceive of a scenario where it seems like a man is *using* his wife or a woman is *using* her husband in youth or old age then, that would be sinful.

***distinguo*** Marriage itself, requires the husband and wife to have "openness to children", an infertile man marrying an fertile woman deprives her of her fertility and vice versa.  It could be a matter of age or injury, in the case of age it could be obvious - as in the case of the French Prime Minister Emmanuel Macron and his wife - this kind of union should not be allowed to take place in the Church. But infertile spouses do not deprive each other of anything and therefore "openness to children" might take another course.

> It must not be forgotten however that, even when procreation is not possible, conjugal life does not for this reason lose its value. Physical sterility in fact can be for spouses the occasion for other important services to the life of the human person, for example, adoption, various forms of educational work, and assistance to other families and to poor or handicapped children.
>
> [John Paul II - familiaris consortio](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/apost_exhortations/documents/hf_jp-ii_exh_19811122_familiaris-consortio.html)

The same can be said of couples where one of the spouses did not know they were infertile, they're not intentionally depriving their spouse of children and likewise, they're not sinning when they make use of the conjugal act, so long as the are not *using* in the negative sense, their spouse.

---

https://www.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_25071968_humanae-vitae.html

https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19870222_respect-for-human-life_en.html

https://ignatius.com/love-and-responsibility-lrep/

https://ignatius.com/50-questions-on-the-natural-law-fqnlp/

Comment: Gotcha - thanks for clarifying Peter!