# Are Catholic Church teachings about homosexuality infallible?

Tags: catholicism, homosexuality, infallibility

The Catholic Church's current teaching regarding homosexuality is that homosexual acts are *peccatum contra natura*. More precisely, the New Catholic Encyclopedia (2003) states:

> Although the Catholic Church recognizes that homosexual attraction is not chosen, and therefore the orientation in itself is not a sin (Catechism of the Catholic Church 2358), it has been the constant tradition in Church teaching, based on Scripture and natural law, that homosexual activity is morally wrong. ... Magisterial Church teaching states that homosexual genital relations are objectively immoral because they ‘‘lack an essential and indispensable finality,’’ namely, the procreative function of sexuality, the openness to new life (Declaration on Certain Questions concerning Sexual Ethics [Dec. 29, 1975] #8). Homosexual activity annuls the goals and meaning of the Creator’s sexual design.

My question: **is this teaching infallible?**

I found [this article](https://www.newwaysministry.org/2020/09/01/polish-bishops-claim-church-teaching-on-homosexuality-is-infallible/) debating a claim by Polish bishops who argue positively about infallibility. Yet, the article challenges this position. I have found surprisingly little material about it (at least from some superficial google search).

Comment: Yes, it's a teaching that has been held by the Church since the days of the Church Fathers. It is infallibly taught by the ordinary and universal magisterium.

Comment: As far as I know, this teaching is valid for any sexual activity that doesn't intend to achieve the goal of procreation. So, homosexuality is as immoral as oral sex between different genders or masturbation.

Comment: I don't know about infallible, but the basic principle seems to be very simple: "*the husband must never intentionally ejaculate outside of his wife’s vagina*" — [According to the Catholic Church, are sex positions that can’t bear children sinful?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90912/according-to-the-catholic-church-are-sex-positions-that-can-t-bear-children-sin/90929#:~:text=West%20writes,vagina).  Homosexual acts clearly violate this requirement.